# i cant add buttons to the actionlistener

Tags: java, swing

hi my Problem was i cant add Buttons to the Action listener
i will made a menu
i dont know why i become a error
here the code
    package lvl;

```
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JButton button;
    private JButton eintellungen;
    private JButton credits;
    private JButton schliessen;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame meinJFrame = new JFrame();
        meinJFrame.setTitle("menu");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();


    JButton button = new JButton("play");
    JButton schliessen = new JButton("schließen");
    JButton eintellungen = new JButton("einstellungen");
    JButton credits = new JButton("credits");
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(schliessen);
    panel.add(credits);
    panel.add(eintellungen);
    credits.addActionListener(this);


    meinJFrame.add(panel);


    meinJFrame.setSize(500, 500);

    meinJFrame.setVisible(true);


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        }


}
```

}
oh i become a error the error says Cannot use this in a static context and it was by credits.addActionListener(this);
please help me

Answer (score 1):

You are in a static context of `public static main`. There is no `this` in static context. Use anonomous class insteed.

```
    credits.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        ////    handle action here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

obviously，your class Main and it's method Main(String[] args) is static,and although your Main implements ActionListener,it cant use cause the method addActionListener need a Object ,static method Main has not 'this' context.
you can

```
credits.addActionListener(new YourActionListener());


        meinJFrame.add(panel);


        meinJFrame.setSize(500, 500);

        meinJFrame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
class YourActionListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

or

```
credits.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
```